# FPDI use template issue

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdi

Has anyone had any experience with fpdi in creating templates to be used on multiple pages.

```
$fpdi->useTemplate($tplidx, 0, 0, 210, 297,true);
```

The above works great for my template but when using writeHTML and the text goes over one page it only applies the template to the current page. Am I doing something wrong or is their some other way around doing this.

Thanks

Comment: This answer seems to apply to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112612/fpdf-fpdi-usetemplate

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [online documentation](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/), I don't think you can.  Each call to `useTemplate()` adds one instance at the given location, but I don't see a way to specify a particular page.

I recommend getting a decent PDF library.  fpdi looks to be designed to convince you to buy Setasign's other products so you can actually accomplish things.  Googling "php pdf" turned up several.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, yes I dont think it offers what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes you can specify a page, you do it when you created $tplidx after instantiating the FPDF class. ($tplidx = $pdf->importpage(1,'/MediaBox');