# FPDI, FPDF SetAutoPageBreak add template to page after break

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I've created a form that allows users to create a pdf that has an unlimited number of pages, I've got SetAutoPageBreak set so that it continues onto a second page however I cannot get the pages created after the page break to continue to use the original template file. The basic code can be seen below.

```
require('fpdf.php');
require('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI('P','mm','A4');

    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("source_file.pdf");
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(63,76,89);
    $pdf->SetMargins(5,39,5,20);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,22); //page created doesn't have template attached
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(225,225,225);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(248,248,248);
    $pdf->SetLineWidth(1);
    $pdf->SetXY(82, 40);
    $pdf->MultiCell(165,5,$company.$block,0,L,false);
    $pdf->SetXY(19, 45);
    $pdf->MultiCell(165,5,$date.$block,0,L,false);
    $pdf->Output();
```

Having looked around, this question is the closest I can find however I'm not sure whether it is even relevant: [FPDF/FPDI UseTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112612/fpdf-fpdi-usetemplate)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the imported page in the Header method:

```
class PDF extends FPDI
{
    protected $_tplIdx;

    public function Header()
    {
        if (null === $this->_tplIdx) {
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        }

        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
...
```

...and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @JanSlabon`s answer: (i dont have the needed reputation to write a comment, so i´ll post this here, hope that´s ok)

If you only want to use a certain template for the first page and a different one for all other pages, you can do so as follows:

```
class PDF extends FPDI
{
    protected $_tplIdx;

    public function Header()
    {
        if (null === $this->_tplIdx) {
            $this->setSourceFile('paper1.pdf');
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        } else {
          $this->setSourceFile('paper2.pdf');
          $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        }

        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);
    }
}
```

i know its not exactly what @Searlee was looking for, but maybe it helps someone else.